# kubernetes multiports with an internal (clusterip) and an external (nodeport) configurations

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

i am using nginx and utilizing the [status stub module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html) by exposing it only to the internal network (i am not using the [allow module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html), but rather using [listen to bind to 127.0.0.1](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)).

i would like to deploy nginx as a service to kubernetes and expose both nginx servers, which are defined in `nginx.conf` (see below), using different [kubernetes service types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). such that the status server endpoint is available only internally within the kubernetes cluster (CluserIP) and the other server endpoint is available externally to the kubernetes cluster ([NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)).

i understand, that the status server at the `nginx.conf` can also be listening to `localhost` and that the kubernetes service configuration could be configured to pass traffic to the status server only from within the kubernetes cluster.

although i tried, i couldn't with the proper kubernetes service configuration to achieve that and would like some help.

here is the nginx configuration (`nginx.conf`)

```
events {
  worker_connections 4000;
  use epoll;
  epoll_events 512;
  multi_accept on;
  accept_mutex on;
}

http {

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
      return 200 'success';
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name _;

    location / {
      stub_status;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: As a general rule, something running in a container that's set to listen or bind to 127.0.0.1 won't be reachable from outside that container.  If you want it to be reachable from elsewhere, even a ClusterIP service, it needs to `listen 0.0.0.0:8080`.

Comment: @DavidMaze: thank you, that is the reason i've updated my post. any idea on how should the k8s service configuration should look like when doing this change?

Comment: The container spec should list both ports; you should have two separate services, both with the same selector, but with different types and targeting different ports in the pods.

Comment: @DavidMaze: i think i understand you and it sounds reasonable. if you kindly convert your comment to an answer, i would accept it (attaching a snippet will be extra nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container spec should list both ports and should have two separate services, both with the same selector, but with different types and targeting different ports in the pods.

And of curse, change the bind address from `127.0.0.1` to localhost (by dropping bind address completely)

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8888
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-status-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9999
      targetPort: 8080
```